# I am facing an issue in retrieving all the list items using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

**Problem :** I have a list of items inside a div class msb-container.
.There are 162 items in the list .I want to click the 150th item from the list .There also a scroll bar through which we can go doen to other elemenst and select it

**How the html looks like :**

```
<div class="mCSB_container" style="position:relative; top:0;">
<ul id="ul-countries">
<li>
 <input id="country-3" type="checkbox" name="c:3">
<label for="country-3">Afghanistan</label>
</li>
<li>
<input id="country-6" type="checkbox" name="c:6">
<label for="country-6">Albania</label>
</li>
---other countries 
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**How my code looks like :**

```
IList<IWebElement> countryList = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='ul-countries']/li"));

    for (int i = 0; i <= countryList.Count; i++)
     {
          string temp = countryList.ElementAt(i).Text;
           if (countryList.ElementAt(i).Text == "Brazil")
           {
               //do something 
           }
     }
```

I am getting a correct count of 162 countries but i think they are not filled correctly .As when I try to retrieve the text from even the 15th country it gives me empty result .It only fills the text for those list item which can be seen on the screen .Although when I inspect element I can see all the required data in list item through html but not through my code .I tried to put the sleep to but no luck .

Please provide your inputs to solve the above issue.
|
Kindest Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
IList<IWebElement> countryList = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='ul-countries']/li"));

for (int i = 0; i <= countryList.Count; i++)
 {
      string temp = countryList.ElementAt(i).findElement(By.CSS("label")).getText();
       if (temp.equals("Brazil"))
       {
           //do something 
       }
 }
```